# Syntax highlighting distorted after installing solarized theme

Tags: intellij-idea

After installing solarized theme in intelliJIdea, syntax highlighting for xml files has been distorted. Below is the snapshot how pom.xml looks like. Any suggestion to fix this. Colors appears for 1 or 2 seconds then seems overridden.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to contact the author of the plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12112-solarized-theme , there's also forum and bug tracker? so you fix all issues faster.